# Why does this regex work in Rubular, but not in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex to parse the [SHOUTcast Total Time Spent Listening report](http://www.shoutcast.com/ttsl.html).

Sample string:

```
#1         6,916,236.75      32,000,555        4,587,363         COOLfahrenheit 93
#2         4,457,026.25      3,328,957         1,168,349         idobi Radio: New. Music. Unfiltered. [url redacted]
```

Regex:

```
^\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.+)$
```

Under [Rubular](http://rubular.com/), this returns:

```
Match 1
1.  6,916,236.75
2.  32,000,555
3.  4,587,363
4.  COOLfahrenheit 93
Match 2
1.  4,457,026.25
2.  3,328,957
3.  1,168,349
4.  idobi Radio: New. Music. Unfiltered. [URL redacted]
```

However, when used with Python's [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents), `None` is returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how did you use it? remember to use raw string: `r"^\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)(.+)$"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't tell for sure without seeing the code, but I'm guessing you forgot to use the multiline flag, [`re.MULTILINE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE).

Ruby is unique in that `^`/`$` *always* match start/end of line. In other common flavors they do not unless the `m` flag is used.

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Also, I should have used `find_all()`.

Comment: Put another way, Ruby is one of the only languages to keep the original behavior of regex from `sed` and POSIX. Other languages (starting with Perl, I believe) invented an unnecessary "multiline" mode instead of just using `\A` and `\Z`. :P